# Create reusable component in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create reusable component in React JS.

The car component is as follows :

```
class cars extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            notification: {
                showNotification: false,
                message: null,
                icon: null
            },
            carID: null
        };
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        let totalCarsPrevious = this.props.carsInCart.length;
        let totalCarsNext = nextProps.carsInCart.length;

        let initNotification = {showNotification: false, message: null, icon: null};
        let notificationRemoved = {showNotification: true, message: notification_messages.removedFromCart, icon: "times"};
        let notificationAdded = {showNotification: true, message: notification_messages.addedToCart, icon: "check"};

        if(totalCarsNext !== totalCarsPrevious){
            this.setState({notification: initNotification}, () => {
                if(totalCarsNext > totalCarsPrevious){
                    this.setState({notification: notificationAdded});
                }else{
                    this.setState({notification: notificationRemoved});
                }
            });
        }
       }

    render() {
         let showNotification = this.state.notification.showNotification ? <Notification message={this.state.notification.message} icon={this.state.notification.icon} /> : "";

         return (
              <div>
                  {showNotification}
                   //Rest of the code ....
              </div>
         )
    }
}
```

In the car component inside `componentWillReceiveProps` I check if the redux store state is changed. If it is changed then I show notification.

Notification component is as follows :

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';

export const notification_messages = {
    addedToCart: "Added",
    removedFromCart: "Removed",
    addToFavorites: "Added to favorites",
    removedFromFavorites: "Removed to favorites"
};

export default class Notification extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            opacity: 0,
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() { this.hideNotification = null; }

    componentDidMount() { this.setTimeout(); }

    setTimeout() {
        this.setState({opacity: 1}, () => {
            this.hideNotification = setTimeout(() => this.setState({opacity: 0}), 2500);
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() { if(this.hideNotification !== null) clearTimeout(this.hideNotification); }

    render() {
        console.log("Pozvana je")
        let {message, icon} = this.props;
        let styles = {opacity: this.state.opacity, transition: "opacity 2s ease"};

        return (
            <div className="notification" style={styles}>
                <div> <FontAwesome name={icon}/> {message} </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Notification.propTypes = {
    message: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    icon: PropTypes.string
};
```

That works perfect. But now I would like to reuse this notification component. I have the same logic for adding to and removing from favorites.

I can do it by adding the same state and the same `componentWillReceiveProps` to the favorites component. I would then only need to check for `this.props.favorites.length` and `nextProp.favorites.length` instead of `this.props.carsInCart.length` and `nextProp.carsInCart.length`.

But is there any way to avoid that?

I would like to add the state and logic from `componentWillReceiveProps` to the notification component and then only call it with the values which I need to compare.

But I need to do that every time when parent component (cars or favorites) receives new props.

Any idea how to do that?